# Looping through 2 different objects in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops

I have the following controller:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {


$scope.taskCategories = {
    categories: [
        'work',
        'chores',
        'learning'
    ]
};

$scope.tasklist = {
    tasks: [{
            title: 'Email Gregory',
            category: 'work'
        }, {
            title: 'Clean the Kitchen',
            category: 'chores'
        }, {
            title: 'AngularJS',
            category: 'learning'
        }, {
            title: 'Hose Car',
            category: 'chores'
        }, {
            title: 'Email Jethro',
            category: 'work'
        }
    ]
};
}]);
```

And am pulling the information through so far like this:

```
<div>
<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#work" class="nav_head workcat collapsed">
    <a href="#">Work <span class="arrow"></span></a>
</li>
<ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="work">
    <li ng-repeat="tasks in tasklist.tasks | orderBy:'title' | filter: {category: 'work'}">
        {{ tasks.title }}
    </li>
    <li class="addwork">
        <a href="">
            <span class="fa-stack"> <i class="fa fa-2x fa-stack-2x fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-2x fa-stack-2x fa-plus-circle"></i> 
    </a>
   </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This would work fine doing a few times, one for each category, but I am looking to be able to add categories dynamically, and so I am looking for some way to go through the following steps:

1. So, I’ll need to loop all in categories.
2. During that loop, I’ll loop through the tasks and print out any task that matches the string of categories.index(1)
3. Then add 1 to category index and run again, till category.length runs out

I'm unfamiliar with looping inside a loop, and more unfamiliar again with doing it in angular. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do an outer loop (ng-repeat) on the categories:

```
<ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="work" ng-repeat="cat in taskCategories.categories">
    <li ng-repeat="tasks in tasklist.tasks | orderBy:'title' | filter: {category: cat}">
        {{ tasks.title }}
    </li>
    <li class="addwork">
        <a href="">
            <span class="fa-stack"> <i class="fa fa-2x fa-stack-2x fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-2x fa-stack-2x fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
        </a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18482/)

Answer (score 2):

Please refer below code snippet

```js
    angular.module('app',[]);

    angular.module('app').controller('myController',function($scope){
        $scope.taskCategories = {
    categories: [
        'work',
        'chores',
        'learning'
    ]
};

$scope.tasklist = {
    tasks: [{
            title: 'Email Gregory',
            category: 'work'
        }, {
            title: 'Clean the Kitchen',
            category: 'chores'
        }, {
            title: 'AngularJS',
            category: 'learning'
        }, {
            title: 'Hose Car',
            category: 'chores'
        }, {
            title: 'Email Jethro',
            category: 'work'
        }
    ]
};

        });
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">
    <ul>
  <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=#{{c}} class="nav_head workcat" ng-repeat="c in taskCategories.categories">
        <a href="#"><span class="arrow"> {{c}}</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id={{c}}>
        <li ng-repeat="tasks in tasklist.tasks | orderBy:'title' | filter: {category: c}">
        {{ tasks.title }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked wonderfully, thanks! Kind of understand the concept a little better too.